# Simplest table in Cloud spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to figure out best practices with Cloud Spanner. The simplest table I can think of is a `Waitlist`, where we store a user's `email` and `timestamp`. The `email` would be the primary key. In another database, I would probably create the table as:

```
CREATE TABLE waitlist (
  email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (email)
);
```

What would be the proper way to do this in Cloud Spanner? My first thought was the following:

```
CREATE TABLE waitlist (
  email STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
  timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL OPTIONS (allow_commit_timestamp = true),
) PRIMARY KEY (email);
```

But I'm wondering, if for example, I would want to add a sort key on `CreationTimestamp` or anything else. To be honest, I'm not really sure what the proper way to create it would be, but maybe I am just overthinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current idea for Cloud Spanner is perfectly fine based purely on the information that you've given in the question. A couple of notes/questions though:

1. `OPTIONS (allow_commit_timestamp = true)` is not the same as a `DEFAULT` value, but it is probably what you want in this case. The difference is that a `DEFAULT` value will insert a value in the column for you if you don't specify anything in your `INSERT` statement, while `OPTIONS (allow_commit_timestamp = true)` will leave the column empty if you don't specify anything for the column in an `INSERT` statement. You need to specify `PENDING_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP()` for the column to actually insert the commit timestamp in the column for an insert, e.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO waitlist (email, `timestamp`)
VALUES ('foo@bar.com', PENDING_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP());
```

2. You write that you might want to add a sort key to `CreationTimestamp`. Adding a (secondary) index where the first column contains monotonically increasing values is an anti-pattern in Cloud Spanner for tables that receive a large number of writes, as it will create a hotspot. See https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design#primary-key-prevent-hotspots. If this table does not receive a lot of writes, then this is less of a problem, and having an index on the column could be an option to improve searching/ordering. What is the reason that you are considering this?

Comment: thanks. One question: `...is not the same as a DEFAULT value, but it is probably what you want in this case. `. Why would you suggest using the above approach then and not using a `DEFAULT` value?

Comment: The difference is that using `default` will insert the timestamp when the DML statement was executed, while `pending_commit_timestamp` will insert the timestamp when the transaction was committed. It of course depends on what your use case is, but the latter is consistent when the record is visible to other transactions (and thereby 'created' as seen by the outside world). The former would be more useful if you need to know the order of creation within one transaction.